# Angular: Prevent URL without param using a guard

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, guard, angular-router-guards

I want to avoid user change the URL from `/dashboard/1234-12` to `/dashboard` to prevent an error, so I want to redirect to `/home` when user type `/dashboard` without the `id`.

I have this **route**:

```js
{
  path: 'dashboard/:id',
  component: DashboardComponent,
  canActivate: [CanActivateViaAuthGuard, CheckVidGuard],
},
```

And this **CheckVidGuard**:

```js
canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): boolean {
  const vid = route?.params?.vid;

  if (!vid) {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

My **Dashboard** component only get this `id` and do some things:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap?.get('id');
}
```

But every time I tried to go to `/dashboard` (without the id param) to get redirected to `/home` I got this error *Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard'*

I know that there is no route defined without the `id` but the guard seems to not work.

I tried adding this route and it works, but I don't want to add other route for this.

```js
{
  path: 'dashboard',
  component: DashboardComponent,
  canActivate: [CanActivateViaAuthGuard],
},
```

With a `Resolver` the result is the same, don't work:

```js
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): string {
  const vid = route.params['vid'];
  if (!vid) {
    this.router.navigate(['/home/dashboard']);
    return null;
  }
  return vid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to https://angular.io/guide/router#route-order

You could just add a dashboard route after the dashboard/{id} route with a rediract to home.

Or have a wildcard route at the and of the config to redirect to home

Comment: Yeah! That's work as I said but... is this a real solution better than use a guard or a resolver? May I have to create redirects for every route I want to control?

Comment: well wildcard routes are the solution for invalid routes..so why not use it.  you can maybe check for the previous url to provide custom logic on redirect. + i dont think your route is called could you verify this

Comment: I finally have implemented the solution with **wildcard**, not sure if it is the correct one but it works.

Answer (score 0):

As [Ivan Tarskich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6236935/ivan-tarskich) said, I have finally implemented the **wildcard** solution using this generic route:

```js
{
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: '/home',
},
```

Not sure if it is the more appropriate solution but it works.